# Regex: matching words (any part in a word), separated by whitespace

Tags: regex, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete. When I enter `aut co`, it should match:

- `Astronaut control`
- `Autonomous company`

But it should **not** match:

- `Autocomplete`

I'm struggling to build the correct regex. I've come so far:

```
/aut(.*)co/i
```

But this matches als `Autocomplete`. So I tried to force a whitespace in between the words:

```
/aut(.*\s.*)co/i
```

But it **still** matches `Autocomplete`.

What do I need to do to make it work as expected?

Comment: Try `^(?!.*\bAutocomplete\b)\S*aut\S* \S*co\S*` https://regex101.com/r/JLBZTq/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
^.*aut[^\s]*\s+[^\s]*co.*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/5tPbXs/2

Comment: But that would also match `Autocomplete Autonomous company` right?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yes. Unfortunately OP does not provide concrete guidelines as to when things should match so I took some liberties in my regex. Per your example my regex would work for `utocomplete Autonomous company` but not `Autocomplete utonomous company` because `aut` and `co` are separated by something other than whitespace. I am sure that there are countless edge-cases for expected behavior but that's OP's problem at this point.